# Necesito que al hacer click en un cuadro de texto de un informe rdlc se abra una página web fija

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer, rdlc

tengo una aplicación de escritorio en c# con un reporte rdlc, necesito que uno de los cuadros de texto de mi reporte funcionen con un vínclulo para que al hacer click se abra el navegador y valla a una url específica, Así de simple.
Ya fui a las propiedades del cuadro de texto, y en Acción le marqué la opción "Ir a dirección url" y luego le puse una url.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También habilité la propiedad EnableHyperlinks

'''reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;'''

Pero cuando ejecuto el reporte es como si no hubiera hecho nada, no funciona.

Por favor espero que me puedan ayudar con esto, ya he probado varias cosas y no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está, el tema es que en el componente Reportviewer no funcionan los link, pero cuando lo salvas a pdf sí (que es lo que yo necesitaba), eso sí, hay que guardar el pdf con el ExportButton, porque si se salva con el PrintButton tampoco funcionan los link.